# Looking to identify a sci-fi book where three men in powered suits explore the deep sea

Tags: story-identification, books

It was a book I read at least 20 years ago. I'm not aware of the original language, the copy I read was translated into Chinese.

The story was about three scientists using powered suits (possibly nuclear), with self-sufficient life-support and recycling systems, to explore deep sea, by walking.

The book described their journey, geography and animals encountered, and I think a large part is about climbing - down into a trench and then back out again. IIRC it took them years to reach land on the other side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They were not in powered suits, but this has some points in common with the 1968 novel [Journey of the Oceanauts](https://books.google.com/books/about/Journey_of_the_Oceanauts.html?id=nVm1HAAACAAJ) by Louise Wolfe.

It has three men who walk across the bottom of the ocean. However, instead of suits they have been surgically altered into 'manfish'.

They also go down into a trench and back up. More details can be found in this [Kirkus Review](https://www.kirkusreviews.com/book-reviews/louis-wolfe/the-journey-of-the-oceanauts/).  If this is the book you may remember some of the training details in which there is a combination of isolation, dark, etc. to prepare candidates for the journey. As this was in 1968 I suspect that type of scene was cribbed from some of the early astronaut training programs which tried to simulate the isolation of space.

> The journey is across the bottom of the Atlantic ocean on foot as young Josh Sparke, his father and ichthyologist Wayne Markham become ""manfish"" a state that is about as believable as the rather watered down characterizations. But this ""inner space"" exploration offer plenty of excitement with mud avalanches, undersea earthquakes and tidal waves, sharks, whales and even an enormous grouper that becomes first a mascot, then a threat. At one point Josh is lost in an immense underground cavern, at another he's buried alive, and still later he's being swept along at over a hundred miles an hour. The pressure isn't just a matter of depth: there's a deadline that they almost miss as the year's supply of air runs out. The somewhat dubious adventures are offset by the number of interesting facts worked in -- ""each codfish lays as many as 9,000,000 eggs at one spawning,"" -- for those who are interested.

Comment: Thanks! I am probably wrong about powered suits, it's been so many years after all. I've found that "three men walking under the sea" isn't a very common theme, so this is probably the book I'm looking for.